# Use javascript to rewrite a URL

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Here is original text:

```
<script src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" data-config="//config.playwire.com/1111111/videos/v2/2222222/zeus.json" data-width="100%" data-height="100%"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

1111111 and 2222222 are the random numbers there.

I want to change `data-config` URL like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" data-config="http://example.net/playwire?pub=1111111&vid=2222222" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So I want to create HTML page with 1 input field, 1 button and 1 text area. When I paste original text into input field, and hit the button then result will be displayed on the text area.

If I use `PHP`, then I will do some `regex` like this:

```
<?php

$text  = '<script src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" data-config="//config.playwire.com/1111111/videos/v2/2222222/zeus.json" data-width="100%" data-height="100%"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $text, $matches);   ?>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100">
<script src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" data-config="http://example.net/playwire?pub=<?php echo $matches[0][0]; ?>&vid=<?php echo $matches[0][2]; ?>" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</textarea>
```

But I want to do it using `javascript`, I don't know how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: *"want to do with javascript"* ... do what exactly? Please be a lot more specific

Comment: @charlietfl :  I'm very bad at javascript, i need a html page with 1 input field, 1 button and 1 text area, when hit the button, onclick event will execute a javascript, that will change data-config url and echo result on text area.

Comment: You can use regular expression in javascript too. search on google

Comment: @Deep : Thank you for edit my question. I know javascript can use regex too, but i'm just don't know how to code. Googling for hour but still can't ...

Answer (score -1):

Where is the script located? if its on the head section you can extract the src attribute with jquery and than do a regular expression on it. you can try something like this:

```
var text = $(window.document.head).children("script").eq(0).attr("src");
var str = text.replace('/[0-9]+/', "sometext");
$(window.document.head).children("script").eq(0).attr("src", str);
```

Comment: Just update question. Sorry for un-clear question, my English is not good.